# Nagios Unable to search for a Log File

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nagios

I have written a simple Shell script for nagios.In the script i am tring to tail a particular file and grep out particular words and mach it with the words i know if the needed words are found it display ok otherwise critical. The plugin seems to be working only when the log file which i am doing tail on is inside /usr/local/nagios/libexec directory not any place else.But i want nagios to search the complete system and then find the desired log file and then perform the needed operation.
Please help

```
check_status()
{

    #!/bin/sh
    word1="flag"                      
    word2="STDOUT"          #wirte the word that you want to 
    find                            
    word3="CALLSTART"           #wirte the word that you want to find 
    word4="Queryyyyselect"
    word5="mobilenumber"
    word6="HLBSA"
    word7="HFA"
    word8="SVA"
    word9="SCA"
    word10="SLBSA"
    a=`timeout 2 tail -f "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/server.log"`

    for word in $word{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    do
        w1=`echo "$a"|egrep -wo "$word"`
        n1=`echo "$w1" | wc -w`
        if [ "$n1" -eq "0" ]; then
            echo "critical: $word not found"
            status=2
        elif [ "$n1" -gt "0" ]; then 
            echo "OK: $word found"
            Status=0
        fi
    done

    return $status
}

check_status
```

Comment: code seems invalid so voting to close

Comment: What's that `#!` doing in the middle of your function? Same question with the bare `find`.

Comment: The #! doesnt belong there but shouldnt hurt; the find is probably from word wrap when copy/pasting. But this is probably a permission problem (nagios user not having access to the real log file) and has nothing to do with the shell.